# Why can't we dereference constant integers?

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting, embedded

In an effort to understand pointers when working with embedded systems, I am trying to understand what is happening in this code that is accessing a memory mapped register:

```
uint32_t regval = *(uint32_t *)0x40048004U;
```

In my mind, without the type casting it means that regval is now equal to the memory contents of the address. I imagine that should be enough but it isn't. But when type casting it, you are treating it like a pointer for a single operation, which seems a bit redundant.

So you are treating regval like the memory contents of an unknown address that points to the memory contents of 0x40048004U? Why is the type casting even necessary?

Comment: It's not redundant. The type of `0x40048004U` is an integer, not a pointer. Remember that it is types that define what operations you can or cannot do on values.

Comment: Because `0x40048004U` is a literal, or constant, `unsigned int`. C does not allow for literal pointers. Note that this kind of cast is a static operation, so there is no runtime performance hit.

Comment: These are great answers, guys, thanks. I actually did not expect such a fast response and am working atm so will have to go over these later. Thanks so much for your time and insight.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, the code is incorrect. When reading a hardware register, you must always do `*(volatile uint32_t *)0x40048004U;`. Otherwise the compiler might do very weird optimizations and the program might not function as intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand you're asking why we can't just do this:

```
uint32_t register_value = *0x40048004U;
```

(i.e. "why can't we dereference constant integers?").

There's a few answers:

- C's syntax for integer constants does not have any annotation for pointer values, only signed/unsigned/short/long values (using `U`, `L`, etc suffices).
- If you *could* do `*0x40048004U` there is no indication of the data-type of the pointer - how many bytes is the computer meant to read from the address? Is it signed? Unsigned? (remember, the type of the constant is concerned with the type of memory address, not the value it points to)
- So by requiring the use of an explicit cast operator `*(valueType*)0xDEADBEFF` means that the type can be specified using the same syntax as a cast of a non-constant value - without needing to introduce a new separate syntax, and as this kind of cast is a static operation there's zero runtime performance hit.

Answer (score 5):

C was designed in a time when memory was small, and thousands of PhD's had not been issued for compiler type inferencing.

While it's possible that in this particular case the compiler might infer that

```
uint32_t regval = *0x40048004U;
```

was supposed to be a dereference of an implied uint32_t pointer, as opposed to a missing parameter in a multiply operation, the reality is that there are cases where it might fail (for example, `int x = 0x00->foo` when there are multiple structures having members named `foo`).

So instead, the requirement was laid down that everything has a type, and if you want to use something as though it were a different type, you have to make that explicit. And it's been that way for 45 years. Fnord.

Comment: IIRC, `0x00->foo` _was_ allowed in some pre-standard code as members had to be unique across structures.  Hence the reason for ancient structures like `struct tm` have members like `tm_min, tm_hour` rather than `min, hour`.

Comment: Some duckducking finds this blog post, with interesting comments from several people who had access to K and/or R: https://spin0r.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/kr-c/ (including Rob Pike)

Answer (score 3):

The pointer-indirection operator `*` can be applied only to pointers.  Its action, of course, is to access the data object pointed to by the pointer.  *But it has to know the size and type of the pointed-to object*.

If you just said

```
uint32_t regval = *0x40048004;
```

the compiler would have no way to know the size and type.  (You might think it's implicit in the fact that you're assigning to a `uint32_2` on the left hand side, but C doesn't work that way.)

If you want something that "remembers" the type, just create and initialize a pointer variable:

```
uint32_t *regptr = (uint32_t *)0x40048004;
uint32_t regval = *regptr;
```

Comment: uv'd, hope you don't mind my correction of your little typo ;) As a little nitpick: "*but C doesn't work that way.*" <- you might want to add "for example because there are some implicit conversions allowed" like, deducing the type of a pointer from an assignment is impossible because an uint32_t could very well be assigned from a uint8_t through implicit conversions.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for the fix.

Comment: And there are *so* many reasons that C doesn't work that way, that I decided not to delve into them at all, which is why I just said "C doesn't work that way"

Answer (score 2):

The type of a pointer determines what the runtime expects to find at the given address *and subsequent addresses*. If the type of `p` is `char *`, for example, `*p` is the single byte at that address. If its type is `int *`, then it expects to find (probably) 4 bytes at that address representing an integer. If the type of `p` is pointer to some 100-byte strucure, then it expect to find 100 bytes of a structure there.

Also, the type determines pointer math. `p + 1` is the address of the next *thing* at p, and might be 1, 4, or 100 bytes later.

Comment: Furthermore, the context does not convey the needed type information.  For example, just because the dereferenced result is assigned to a variable of type `uint32_t` does not mean that the pointed-to object must be of that type, as opposed to, say, an `int64_t` or a `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that the integer constant will be used as the pointer. You need to show the compiler what type of object this pointer points to. And next you get the value of the object pointed by this pointer (in this case it will be 32 bit word).

Answer (score 0):

Type casting a pointer *is not* necessary; `0x40048004U` is not a pointer.  The cast reinterprets the literal constant *integer* as a pointer.

Moreover, even when 0x40048004U is interpreted as an address, the compiler needs to know what data type it points to when it is dereferenced.